# require() resolution in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, metro-bundler

I'm trying to find out why `require('foo/bar.png')` works differently in two RN projects

In one project, foo is registered as root via metro.config.js

```
  extraNodeModules: {
    foo: path.join(__dirname, 'src/foo'),
  }
```

In another project, foo lives in under app_root/node_modules

```
so foo is at app_root/node_modules/foo
```

So in both projects, I can do `import something from 'foo/something'`

But when it comes to `require`, two projects behave differently..

---

There is a line in `foo/components/hello.js`

```
 require('foo/assets/image.png')
```

In the first project, the image file is correctly found,

But second project complains that it can't find with an error `/path/to/root_project/node_modules/foo/component/node_modules/foo/assets/image.png`

It seems as if `require` is assuming that where the `require` is called should be the project root or something.

Where should I look for or how do I debug this?

Can I print module.paths in ReactNative project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is path is same for both project ? If in first project **require()** works then it should be work on second project, one reason for not working that your path is not correct in second project. Therefore check it again.

Comment: I ended up moving from `node_modules/foo` to `src/foo`

Answer (score 0):

Require is not a React statement - it is Node.js statement, use import instead.